# Custom End points API to get all themes from word-press returning False value

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, wordpress-rest-api

Here is the custom end points What i have created here for getting all themes. But in json it’s not returning result as expected.

```
add_action( ‘rest_api_init’, function () {
//Path to rest endpoint
register_rest_route( ‘theme/v1’, ‘/get_theme_list/’, array(
‘methods’ => ‘GET’,
‘callback’ => ‘theme_list_function’
) );
});
// Our function to get the themes
function theme_list_function(){
// Get a list of themes
$list = wp_get_themes();
// Return the value
return $list;
}

?>
```

If I can see simply the wp_get_themes() function it will return all the themes and its description in arrays. and It’s return fine in arrays but when i am encoding this into json to pass data its returning only array keys.

Producing only key name like in this way

```
All: {"basepress":{"update":false},"codilight-lite":{"update":false},"twentyfifteen":{"update":false},"twentyseventeen":{"update":false},"twentysixteen-child":{"update":false},"twentysixteen":{"update":false}}
```

I need all the information about the themes.

How can i do that with custom REST end points.

Please help.

Comment: above the code returning all the information.

Comment: @vel the above code is working fine to returning arrays if i am going to encode it to json so its not giving response as per the arrays in updates parameter it's giving false value while in array it's returning all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
//Path to rest endpoint
    register_rest_route( 'theme/v1', '/get_theme_list/', array('methods' => 'GET','callback' => 'theme_list_function') );
});
// Our function to get the themes
function theme_list_function(){
    // Get a list of themes
    $list = wp_get_themes();

    $varTheme = array();

    foreach($list as $theme=>$value){
        $varTheme[$theme] = (array)$value;
    }
    return $varTheme;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vel Now, I am able to getting all the information about the theme except the theme appearance feature image path how can i get that too.

Comment: it is default name is screenshot.png and by the way `wp_get_themes` doest not return value. you can use `theme_url/ screenshot.png` to get `theme appearance feature image path`